# How to remove just script tags and its content by keeping all other tags intact in Python

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to sanitize HTML content in python. I tried using `lxml.html.clean` as below

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
from lxml import html

cleaner = Cleaner(page_structure=False, safe_attrs=html.defs.safe_attrs | set(['style']), scripts=True)
cleaned_html_content = cleaner.clean_html(html_content),
```

The  tag is getting removed, but some attributes are also getting removed like `<input type="checkbox" checked disabled>` is also getting removed. Can I remove only the `<script>` tags with `lxml.html.clean`?

Comment: This sounds like a potentially dangerous idea for removing scripts... You can have `javascript:` in links for example. I think this is also how myspace was famously hacked. In my view, the only robust solution is a tag whitelist, I would use the `bleach` library.

Comment: I recommend reading about Samy Kamkar's famous myspace exploit: https://samy.pl/myspace/tech.html It's a fascinating read and it shows how unsafe it is to simply remove script tags. (You can also use attributes for example)